# Compute $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+j)^p}$ for $p>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Compute $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+j)^p}$$ for $p>0$.

The given solution in the text is as following

[image]

Can anyone please explain this...

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Tried to think of any function whose derivative would give me anything similar to this but to no avail

Comment: What is your problem precisely?

Comment: how the equality between summation in $n$ and $(i,j)$ arises

Comment: In how many ways can you write a given $n \ge 2$ as a sum of two positive integers?

Comment: It's strange that the question asks to compute the sum, but the answer only shows that it converges.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is the full answer, I am not cutting any part out

Comment: @Gary the number of ways $= \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1 $

Comment: Note that since there is now restriction like $j \le i$, $4=1+3$ and $4=3+1$, for example, are two different ways of doing it for $n=4$. In one case $i=1$, $j=3$, in the other $i=3$, $j=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\sum_{i,k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(i+k)^{p}} &= \sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{\{i,k \,:i+k=n\}}\frac{1}{(i+k)^{p}}\\ &=\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{\{i,k\,:i+k=n\}}\frac{1}{n^{p}}.\end{align}

Now for each $i$, there is only one $k$ namely $n-i$ such that $i+k=n$ and vice-versa. The number of such $i,k :i+k=n$ is exactly the number of ways you can chose $i$ which is $n-1$ (We exclude $n$ as then $k=0$.). What you are confusing with is #$\{i,k:i+k=n , i\leq k\}=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor +1$. (Which even in this case would lead to the same conclusion as to what $p$ should be.)

So what you have is $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(n-1)}{n^{p}}$ which as $\frac{n-1}{n}\sim 1$ converges or diverges as $\sum\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}$ converges or diverges. It's well known that the above converges for $p-1>1$ and diverges for $p-1\leq 1$ .

Also, you cannot really compute closed forms of the series. The most you can do is that for $p>2$, you can write $$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n-1}{n^{p}}=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{n^{p}} = \zeta(p-1)-\zeta(p).$$